# how to write ctx.Load in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Blow is a C# example to get Site Pages in SharePoint:

```
var listTitle = "Site Pages";
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items, **icol => icol.Include( i => i["WikiField"], i => i["CanvasContent1"], i => i["FileRef"], i => i.ContentType**));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
     Console.WriteLine(">>> {0}", item["FileRef"]);
     switch (item.ContentType.Name)
     {
        case "Site Page":
          Console.WriteLine(item["CanvasContent1"]);
          break;
        case "Wiki Page":
          Console.WriteLine(item["WikiField"]);
          break;

     }    
 }
```

My question is: in ctx.Load() method, how to write the part lik "i =>" in powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I convert the C# code to the PowerShell script below for your reference.

```
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team"
$UserName="admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="xxxx"
$ListName="Site Pages"

Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$List = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$ctx.Load($List.ContentTypes)
$ctx.Load($ListItems)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($item in $ListItems){
    $ContentType = $List.ContentTypes| Where {$_.Id.ToString() -eq $item["ContentTypeId"].ToString()}
    Write-host $item["FileRef"]
    if($ContentType.Name -eq "Site Page"){  
        Write-host $item["CanvasContent1"]
    }
    if($ContentType.Name -eq "Wiki Page"){  
        Write-host Write-host $item["WikiField"]
    }   
}
```

Comment: btw, in which doc describe these field "FileRef","WikiField", etc? I want to check what other fields I can use for item[].

Comment: Check the article here: https://blog.softartisans.com/2009/12/08/list-of-internal-names-for-sharepoint-fields/, if my reply help you, please mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know which types `ctx.Load` requires I'll post a LINQ based example, showing how to define delegates.

You can define a delegate like this:

```
[Func[int,bool]] $delegate = { param($n) ; $n % 2 -eq 0 }
```

Below example uses LINQ to dump even numbers:

```
[int[]]$numbers = 1 .. 100
[Func[int,bool]] $delegate = { param($n) ; $n % 2 -eq 0 }
[Linq.Enumerable]::Where($numbers, $delegate)
```

Here is a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##RY2xDoIwGIR3nuKGmkCCTXHEOOrEztB0aPWPkJS/UCEOxmevdTDeePfluzk8KT4G8j4lPfKqjRG8TS6XOKGBlGiUKvRl4@t3r10I3hiIG3m625UylfPCbKOdSsEVjhCMHQ7Y0wKFd6G7kRd5zlqK1nkybdsPFKn8PdV/XZXSBw) to an online example.

If you want lambda style you can write:

```
[int[]]$numbers = 1 .. 100
[Linq.Enumerable]::Where($numbers, [Func[int,bool]] { param($n) ; $n % 2 -eq 0 })
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: although I don't know about LINQ, still thanks for your answers!